# Regex replacement using named group in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I need some help with my regex replacement used named group in VBScript. I have the following code where I want to replace version by regex statement:

```
content = "#define VERSION 1000"
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.MultiLine = True
regEx.Global = True
regEx.Pattern = "(?<Name>\#define\s+VERSION\s+)(?<Value>\d+)"

newContent=regEx.Replace(content,"$1"&versionBuild)
```

I receive error:

```
Syntacs error in regular expression.
```

How to use named group in regular expresssion correctly?

Answer (score 2):

VBScript regular expressions do not allow named groups.

Change your pattern into `(#define\s+VERSION\s+)\d+`. There will be a *capture* group to retrieve the start of the line for your `"$1" & versionBuild` replace expression